# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Sequence Not Working - keeps incrementing sequence by 2

Tags: sql-server-2012, sequences

I just installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and I'm using Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server (sqljdbc4.jar v4.0.2206.100) to access the database remotely.

I have tried many variations and searched far and wide but for some reason, sequences keep incrementing by 2, not 1.

Example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MYSEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999 CYCLE
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MYSEQ - this actually returns 2, not 1 - but that's fine
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MYSEQ - this returns 4, not 3 - that's a problem
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MYSEQ - this returns 6, not 4 - that's a problem
etc
```

And it doesn't matter what the START WITH value is.

If I change to use INCREMENT BY 2, it increments by 4 all the time.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce this in SQL Server 2012 - works as designed, returns `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ......`. There must be something else going on in your code/environment that causes this behavior - but it's **NOT** SQL Server 2012's fault, I would assume

Comment: I found the issue.  My JDBC string had: jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;DatabaseName=<name>;selectMethod=cursor;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false.  When I remove everything after the database name, it works fine.  Sorry!

Comment: You should put that down as an answer to your own question - maybe that'll help someone else who stumbles across the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC string I was using was:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[host]:[port];DatabaseName=[name];selectMethod=cursor;sendStrin‌gParametersAsUnicode=false
```

When I changed the string to:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[host]:[port];DatabaseName=[name]
```

The sequences returned were as expected: 1, 2, 3, etc

Comment: Wow, I would not have thought that the selectMethod makes a difference. Seems like a driver bug to me. The jTDS driver does not seem to have this behaviour when using cursors.