# Why is SQL Server sequence jumping by two when fetched from Java code?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Let's say there is a sequence created on SQL Server:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.my_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO CYCLE;
GO
```

And the following Java code to fetch the next sequence value:

```java
Connection conn = ...;
String sql = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR my_seq;";

try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql)) {
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        long seq = resultSet.getLong(1);

        System.out.println(seq);
    }
}
```

Why are sequences jumping by two when this code is executed repeatedly?

```
2
4
6
```

I've tried with the `CACHE` option on and off. It makes no difference.

Sequences are incremented by one if I execute the same query multiple times on Azure Data Studio.

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64). I tried the same code with `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:10.2.0.jre8` and `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:11.1.1.jre8-preview` drivers and got the same behavior.

I analyzed the SQL Server query history, and the Java code made only one query to fetch the next sequence value per execution.

Comment: How is the _"code ... executed repeatedly"_?  Any other process accessing the same sequence?

Comment: Just a guess - have you tried to call resultSet.setFetchSize(1) before you call resultSet.next() for the first time?

Comment: @JimGarrison the code is called multiple times in the context of my application. Anyway, the same problem occurs if I put a for loop around the code. No other process is accessing the SQL Server, and the number of performed queries in the query history matches the number of operations executed by my application.

Comment: @rmunge I did it after reading your comment. It makes no difference. Same behavior.

Comment: After some research and much trial-and-error, I found this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62649517/10586727) and learned about the `sys.sp_sequence_get_range` stored procedure. I worked out a solution using a `CallableStatement` that doesn't skip numbers after repeated executions. Still, why isn't the `NEXT VALUE FOR` function working as expected?

Comment: In case it's relevant, these two threads mention similar issues due to resultset and cursor type. You might try different settings to see if there's a change in the behavior.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062938/microsoft-sql-server-2012-sequence-not-working-keeps-incrementing-sequence-by  ... and ... https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1174

Comment: @SOS I'll take a look at them. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @SOS nailed it! The problem is related to the `selectMethod=cursor`. The framework I used to connect to the database was silently adding this option to the connection URL, causing this behavior. I'll write a response for future reference.

Comment: Great, and thanks for adding the solution to the archives!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Gary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18076979/10586727) to a similar question, this is a known behavior when using the `selectMethod=cursor` option. Just remove this option from the connection URL, and sequence numbers won't skip anymore.

What if you must use `selectMethod=cursor` for some reason? Then try the `sys.sp_sequence_get_range` stored procedure instead as demonstrated below.

```java
Connection conn = ...;
String sequenceName = "my_seq";

try (CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall("{call sys.sp_sequence_get_range(?, ?, ?)}")) {
    statement.setString("sequence_name", sequenceName);
    statement.setLong("range_size", 1);
    statement.registerOutParameter("range_first_value", microsoft.sql.Types.SQL_VARIANT);
    statement.execute();

    long seq = statement.getLong("range_first_value");
    
    System.out.println(seq);
}
```

It doesn't skip sequence numbers even if the `selectMethod=cursor` option is enabled.